# Why can't I create a command in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

How to create a Discord.py command?

In fact, it doesn't show anything in the console at all, what should I do?

There's no error, nothing is executing.

```py
import discord
import time

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

# This detects when the bot started.

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print(f'{client.user.name} is ready!')

# This detects when someone sends a message.

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:

        return

    if 'fuck' in message.content:

        await message.delete()

        async with message.channel.typing():

            time.sleep(1)

        await message.channel.send('You cannot swear in this discord server!')

    if 'shit' in message.content:

        await message.delete()

        async with message.channel.typing():

            time.sleep(1)

        await message.channel.send('You cannot swear in this discord server!')

    if 'bitch' in message.content:

        await message.delete()

        async with message.channel.typing():

            time.sleep(1)

        await message.channel.send('You cannot swear in this discord server!')

    if 'https://' in message.content:

        await message.delete()

        async with message.channel.typing():

            time.sleep(1)

        await message.channel.send('You cannot send links in this discord server!')

# This cteates a command.

@commands.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):

    async with message.channel.typing():

        time.sleep(1)

    await ctx.send(arg)

client.add_command(test)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `client.process_commands` at the end of the `on_message` event.

```py
async def on_message(message):
    # ...

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Another thing wrong in your code is that you're not defining `message` in the `test` command, you can fix it by using the `Context.message` attribute

```py
async with ctx.message.typing():
    # ...

# Or
async with ctx.typing():
    # ...
```

Also you can simply use the `client.command` decorator instead of `commands.command` so you don't need to add the line `client.add_command`

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    # ...
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [`Context.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20message#discord.ext.commands.Context.message)
- [`Context.typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20typing#discord.ext.commands.Context.typing)